# Yaroslavsky Dual-pivot Quicksort Java implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I'd like to ask you if you can show me how my code might look like so I might not get java.lang.StackOverflowError during the sort of 100000 ints (My implementation is good but only to 20000 numbers , bigger sizes of table to sort will produce that error). I've tryied to change the size of heap in InteliJ , but that way seems not to be working.Also I've spend like 2 hours trying to modyfy it and reading about it over the web , yet I can't overcome this problem. That's why I'm asking you guys , to show me where can I change my code in my implementation so I won't recive that error.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class YaroslawskiSort {
Random gener;
public int temporary,genertype,NInts;
ArrayList<Integer> mylist;

public YaroslawskiSort(int type,int ilosc){
    gener = new Random();
    mylist= new  ArrayList<>();
    this.genertype=type;
    this.NInts=ilosc;

}

void generate(){
    if(genertype==0){
        for(int i=0;i<NInts;i++){
            mylist.add(gener.nextInt(100000));
        }
    }else {
        for(int i=0;i<NInts;i++){
            mylist.add(NInts-i);
        }
    }
}

void sortingI(int left,int right) {
    for (int i=left+1;i<=right;i++)
    {
        int value = mylist.get(i);
        int j =i-1;
        while (j >= left && mylist.get(j)>value)
        {
            mylist.set(j+1,mylist.get(j));
            j--;
        }
        mylist.set(j+1,value);
    }

}
private void sorting( int left, int right) {

    if((right-left)>=17) {
        int[] index=new int[2];
        index = partition(left, right);
        if (left < index[0]) {
            sorting(left, index[0]);
        }
        if(index[0]<index[1]){
            sorting(index[0], index[1]);
        }
        if (index[1] < right) {
           sorting(index[1], right);
        }


    }

    if((right-left)<17 && (right-left)!=0){
    sortingI(left,right);                               //INSERTION SORT!
    }
}

private int[] partition( int left, int right) {

    int pivot1 = mylist.get(left);
    int pivot2 = mylist.get(right);
    if(pivot1>pivot2){
       mylist.set(left,pivot2);
        mylist.set(right,pivot1);
        temporary=pivot1;
        pivot1=pivot2;
        pivot2=temporary;
    }
    int L=left+1;
    while(mylist.get(L)<pivot1 && L<right){
        L++;
    }
    int K=L;
    while( K<=right&& mylist.get(K)>=pivot1 && mylist.get(K)<=pivot2 ){
        K++;
    }
    int G=right-1;
    while(mylist.get(G)>pivot2 && G>left){
        G--;
    }


    while (K <= G) {
        if(mylist.get(K)<pivot1){
            mylist.add(left+1,mylist.remove(K));
            L++;
            K++;
        }
        if(mylist.get(K)>=pivot1 && mylist.get(K)<=pivot2){
            mylist.add(L,mylist.remove(K));
            K++;
        }
        if(mylist.get(K)>pivot2){
            mylist.add(right,mylist.remove(K));
            G--;
        }

    }

    mylist.set(left,mylist.get(L-1));
    mylist.set(L-1,pivot1);

    mylist.set(right,mylist.get(G+1));
    mylist.set(G+1,pivot2);
    int[] table=new int[2];
    table[0]=L;
    table[1]=G;

    return table;
}

void printing(){
    for(int k=0;k<NInts;k++){
        System.out.print(" "+mylist.get(k));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){

            YaroslawskiSort instance = new YaroslawskiSort(1,100000);
            instance.generate();
            instance.sorting(0, instance.mylist.size() - 1);

            instance.printing();

    }
}
```

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working good, to increase stack size open Edit configuration... of your project in intellij IDEA (top right corner) and in field VM options type -Xss16m. If you do so, you will not get StackOverflowError.

In my opinion you get StackOverflow cause you're recursively call **sorting** method and it in its turn call **partition** method where always a new int[2] is created and all of these arrays are on stack.

If you can rewrite partition method so it (for example) return int and call it for left and right bound separately, I think this will fix the problem.